# Fixed Width and Height Div of pushing down Text because of Font-Size

Tags: html, css

I'm doing a little project that manipulates HTML. I'm trying to position text in the center of a `div` that has a fixed height and fixed width. Everything is positioned `absolute`. However, setting the font-size pushes the text down from the actual rectangle. On the same page, I have another rectangle (not shown in the example below) where it works fine (because of a smaller font maybe?) Can someone explain to me what's going on, and how I can solve my problem?

```css
.wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  width: 120px;
  height: 72px;
  border-color: #000000;
  border-style: dotted;
}

#LetterBox.position {
  position: absolute;
  top: -4.719643044619423px;
  left: 13.15069816272966px;
}

#LetterBox.shape {
  width: 99.41917060367455px;
  height: 64.46308661417323px;
  background: red;
}

#LetterBox .font {
  font-size: 41px; /*culprit*/
  font-family: "lucida grande", Times, serif;
  color: #222222;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" id="layout">
  <div id="LetterBox" class="position shape">
    <p class="font">a</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To centre text use `display:table` property on parent div and `display:table-cell` on the text element.

Here is the working code(I have not centered the red background div as that is not the question):

```css
.wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  width: 120px;
  height: 72px;
  border-color: #000000;
  border-style: dotted;
}

#LetterBox.position {
  position: absolute;
  top: -4.719643044619423px;
  left: 13.15069816272966px;
}

#LetterBox.shape {
  width: 99.41917060367455px;
  height: 64.46308661417323px;
  background: red;
  display: table;
}

#LetterBox .font {
  font-size: 41px; /*culprit*/
  font-family: "lucida grande", Times, serif;
  color: #222222;
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell; 
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" id="layout">
  <div id="LetterBox" class="position shape">
    <p class="font">a</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Another example with smaller font:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  width: 120px;
  height: 72px;
  border-color: #000000;
  border-style: dotted;
}

#LetterBox.position {
  position: absolute;
  top: -4.719643044619423px;
  left: 13.15069816272966px;
}

#LetterBox.shape {
  width: 99.41917060367455px;
  height: 64.46308661417323px;
  background: red;
  display: table;
}

#LetterBox .font {
  font-size: 30px; /*culprit*/
  font-family: "lucida grande", Times, serif;
  color: #222222;
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell; 
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" id="layout">
  <div id="LetterBox" class="position shape">
    <p class="font">a</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hopefully this is what you need.

Comment: @MangoBoy Is this what you need?

Comment: Thanks! That worked! Exactly what I need it seems like. Why does that work though?

Comment: @MangoBoy Css tables are unlike html tables. You make the parent as the complete table unit and make its child as a cell. After that you can apply vertical-align:middle to that cell. If this is the correct solution to your problem do accept it. :)

Comment: @MangoBoy Also if you add more content it will dynamically adjust.

Comment: so I'm getting unexpected behavior with this when I have a div with fixed height (no content). e.g div with height 100px and width 100px with a border. The fixed height is not being rendered, so it just looks look like a line

Comment: I read that display:table ingnores height because of content, but for my layout where everything is absolute, I need to preserve that property

Comment: https://codepen.io/rlingineni/pen/oympor -It works here, but in production, the height under the "computed" tab is being set to 0px

Comment: @MangoBoy Try using min-height:100px !important; to the div

Comment: @MangoBoy Removing content works fine for me too same as in the codepen. I cannot know the styling of the div which is used such that this code is not working..

Comment: Ohh, I think I figured out the problem. It seems that when you do `display:table`, there needs to be some content inside of it. I added a blank div into the wrapping element and then the height value is rendered as it should. Cheers.